# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' error

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, nsurl

Ok, so I know that this is a common error, but I can not find anything that can help me with it online.

When I input:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"backgroundLoop" ofType:@"m4a"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[theAudio play];
```

into my app (in the -ViewDidLoad method), I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL
> initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
>
> First throw call stack: (0x1a31022 0x1ed9cd6 0x19d9a48 0x19d99b9 0xcad53b 0xcad4c5 0x2f85 0x10cba1e 0x102a401 0x102a670 0x102a836
> 0x103172a 0x2d8d 0x1002386 0x1003274 0x1012183 0x1012c38 0x1006634
> 0x317fef5 0x1a05195 0x1969ff2 0x19688da 0x1967d84 0x1967c9b 0x1002c65
> 0x1004626 0x2bbc 0x2b55) terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Please note: I am using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

The file probably doesn't exist at the path you're passing to `-initFileURLWithPath:`. What is the value of `path` before making the call? It's probably nil, would be my guess.

Comment: the value of path is not directly shown before it is called.  Should I put that in? and if so, how?

Comment: You can print it by typing `po path` at the debug console prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Just use NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"%@", path);
```

see if the file name is same.